# Проверка имени preg match

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, как с помощью `preg_match` проверить соответствие на `любые буквы на любом языке`, `0-9`, `_` и `-`?

Comment: Так `'~^\w+$~u'`?

Comment: @MaximTimakov, минус забыли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$emptyAllowed = false;

if ($emptyAllowed) {
    $reg_exp = '~^[\\w-]*$~u'; // если пустая строка подходит
}
else {
    $reg_exp = '~^[\\w-]+$~u'; // если нужен минимум символ
}

var_dump(preg_match($reg_exp, '嗨-Ёшкин_Код-XD'));
var_dump(preg_match($reg_exp, 'Ты не пройдёшь!'));
```

Для указания интервала вместо `+` можно использовать `{min,max}`, где `min` и `max` - границы

- [Wikipedia : Регулярные выражения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)
- [php.net : preg_match](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score -1):

Например, так:

```
$regex = '/[\w \- \_]/ui';
if( preg_match($regex, $str) )
{ 
... 
}
```

Вместо `$str` подставляешь строку, где нужно делать проверку.

Comment: Автор вопроса просил на любом языке, неужели вы думаете, что все языки мира основаны на английском и русском алфавитах ?

Comment: Я написал пример. Думаю, дальше человек уже сможет разобраться, что ему нужно добавить в код...

Comment: И ему по вашему примеру стоит перечислить например все китайские иероглифы ? И это в то время, когда в регулярных выражениях _любой_ буквенно-цифровой символ обозначается просто `\w` как раз что бы не задумываться какие буквы нужны а какие нет. И кстати запятые он вроде не просил, а у вас их зачем то аж две штуки

Comment: Ну значит я этого не знал. Написал то что знал и чем пользовался все это время сам.

Comment: @Tennik, у вас и сейчас регулярное выражение неверное.

Comment: `'/[\w \- \_]/ui'` разрешит ввод любой строки, содержащей букву, цифру, пробел, дефис или `_`. К тому же, `/i`, `\_` лишние.

Comment: Будьте добры, подскажите, как верно.